# A Riley - Half by humans, Half by the God

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My prefix is an animal,

My infix is what restricts my prefix,

My suffix is an expression.

Made half by the humans and half by the God.

What am I?

Comment: I found a [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-name-of-a-thing-which-is-half-made-by-God-and-half-made-by-men) that might serve useful. Does the riddle refer to this? Particularly the title?

Comment: @user477343 no. This riddle has nothing to do with the link.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Fishhook.

My prefix is an animal,

> Fish

My infix is what restricts my prefix,

> Hook

My suffix is an expression.

> Ok

Made half by the humans and half by the God.

> There is some Hawaiian mythology

Comment: A good guess but no.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> suffix=vow (synonym of covenant, but shorter)